# Comparing class objects using template max function

Tags: c++

I have written a template function like this:

```
template <class T>
const T& max1(const T& x, const T& y)
{
  if(y < x)
    return x;
  return y;
}
```

Now, how can I use this function to compare two objects of class A where class A is like the following?

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int x){i=x;}
```

private:
    friend bool operator<(A const& lhs, A const& rhs) 
    {
        return lhs.i < rhs.i;
    }

`int i;`

};

I believe I have to overload < operator but could not figure out how this whole process is working? Could you also provide a link to articles where I can read about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining an overloaded `<` operator is simple in this case:

```
bool operator<(A const& lhs, A const& rhs) {
    return lhs.i < rhs.i;
}
```

In general, defining overloaded operators is as simple as that (though if you want to access non-public members, you will need to `friend` the function within the class's definition).

Some operator overloads (like `[]`, `()`, `=`) cannot be defined as free functions, but instead must be member functions. This isn't any harder than defining free-function overloaded operators, but is something to be aware of.

Comment: <code>  class A
  {
  public:
 A(int x){i=x;}
 
 int operator<(A const& lhs, A const& rhs) 
 {
  lhs.i < rhs.i? lhs.i: rhs.i;
 }
 
 int i;
 
  };
 
  int main() 
  {
  
   A a(10), b(20);
   //std::cout << max1(a, b) << std::endl;
   return 0;
  }
</code>
is providing me compiler error like error: ‘int A::operator<(const A&, const A&)’ must take exactly one argument

Comment: @user243655: The `operator<` function I pasted above has to be a free function (outside of the class's definition). Also, `operator<` has to return a `bool` specifying whether the left-hand side is less than the right-hand side.

Comment: It could also be a free friend function inside the class definition, which is how I tend to write it. `class A { public: int i; private: friend bool operator<(A const& lhs, A const& rhs) { return lhs.i < rhs.i; }};`

Comment: If I declare the operator < as friend, and pass two arguments it works. However, if I try this 
<pre><code>
bool operator <(A& rhs)
 {
  return i < rhs.i;
 }
</code></pre>

It provides me compiler error. Could you let me know why?

Comment: @user243655: Because you need to qualify both `lhs` and `rhs` as `const`. Try this: `bool operator<(A const& rhs) const {...}`. (Notice the `const` in two places.)

Answer (score 1):

Specialize `max`:

```
template <> const T& max1(const A& x, const A& y)
{
  if(y.i < x.i)
    return x;
  return y;
}
```

Comment: I want to use the same max function for int, double, and classes as well.